# postgres query with IN is very slow

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have a table which has an index on (column A, column B). And I'm running a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (A, B) IN ((a_1, b_1), (a_2, b_2), ..., (a_5000, b_5000))
```

This query is very slow !
The plan looks like:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on table
  Recheck Cond: (((A = a_1) AND (B = b_1)) OR ((A = a_2) AND (B = b_2)) OR ...
  ->  BitmapOr
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx
              Index Cond: ((A = a_1) AND (B = b_1))
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx
              Index Cond: ((A = a_2) AND (B = b_2))
        ...(5000 other Bitmax Index Scan)
```

Instead of doing one index scan with 5000 values, postgres seems to be doing 5000 index scan with one value at a time, which explains why the query is so slow.

Actually it is way faster to do someting like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE A IN (a_1, ..., a_5000)
```

fetch the results and then filter on column B inside the app (python).

I'd really prefer to have the results already filtered by postgres with a reasonable running time. Is there a workaround ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try joining to a CTE:

```
with value_list (a,b) as (
  values 
      (a_1, b_1), 
      (a_2, b_2), ..., 
      (a_5000, b_5000) 
)
select *
from table t
  join value_list v on (t.a, t.b) = (v.a, v.b);
```

(This assumes you have no duplicates in the list of values)

Comment: That's interesting. Why should it make any difference?

Comment: @zerkms: the theory (hope) is that it will trick the optimizer to do a single index scan for all values rather then one scan for each value.

Comment: It works ! The planner uses indeed just one hashjoin. I find it weird though that the planner isn't smart enough to deal with the first query.

Comment: @MehdiGMIRA: for a single column IN list the optimizer works fine. It's just this case that it doesn't handle in the best way - but Postgres isn't alone. Oracle won't consider an index at all for `(a,b) in (...)` even if the condition only returns a small fraction of the table. On my laptop with a table with 700.000 rows the IN query on Postgres takes only 1.5 seconds to return 1000 rows. Oracle needs 50 seconds. So even if the plan isn't perfect, it's actually not that bad.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's impressive!