# Why this query is so slow? - PostgreSQL - selecting from SERIAL, TIMESTAMP and NUMERIC(6,2)

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

This is my `measurement_pm2_5` table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.measurement_pm2_5 (
  sensor_id SERIAL,
  measurement_time TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
  measurement_value NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT measurement_pm2_5_sensor_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (sensor_id)
    REFERENCES public.sensor(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    NOT DEFERRABLE
) 
WITH (oids = false);
```

And this is my query:

```
select sensor_id, measurement_time, measurement_value 
FROM "public"."measurement_pm10" p, 
      (values(64,1476094463,1476116063),(129,1476094463,1476116063),(66,1476094463,1476116063),(130,1476094463,1476116063),(3,1476094463,1476116063),(131,1476094463,1476116063),(132,1476094463,1476116063),(133,1476094463,1476116063),(134,1476094463,1476116063),(135,1476094463,1476116063),(136,1476094463,1476116063),(137,1476094463,1476116063),(138,1476094463,1476116063),(139,1476094463,1476116063),(142,1476094463,1476116063),(17,1476094463,1476116063),(18,1476094463,1476116063),(19,1476094463,1476116063),(148,1476094463,1476116063),(94,1476094463,1476116063),(96,1476094463,1476116063),(101,1476094463,1476116063),(58,1476094463,1476116063),(59,1476094463,1476116063),(60,1476094463,1476116063),(63,1476094463,1476116063)) as t(sensor,t1,t2)
WHERE p.sensor_id = t.sensor 
  AND measurement_time BETWEEN to_timestamp(t.t1) AND to_timestamp(t.t2);
```

It takes about 16 seconds for the database to execute it and give a response.
It returns about 3k rows. Generally, there are 260k rows in this table.

Is there any way to make it faster? By faster I mean to execute it in less than a second?

I use AWS's free tier's PostgreSQL database.

`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFER)`:

```
Hash Join  (cost=0.65..8056.77 rows=5835 width=18) (actual time=15308.237..16039.319 rows=3035 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (p.sensor_id = "*VALUES*".column1)
  Join Filter: ((p.measurement_time >= to_timestamp(("*VALUES*".column2)::double precision)) AND (p.measurement_time <= to_timestamp(("*VALUES*".column3)::double precision)))
  Rows Removed by Join Filter: 182836
  Buffers: shared hit=2330
  ->  Seq Scan on measurement_pm10 p  (cost=0.00..5538.74 rows=321174 width=18) (actual time=0.007..1657.386 rows=321229 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=2327
  ->  Hash  (cost=0.33..0.33 rows=26 width=12) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=26 loops=1)
        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 10kB
        ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..0.33 rows=26 width=12) (actual time=0.002..0.010 rows=26 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.560 ms
Execution time: 16040.164 ms
```

Comment: Probably relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39246869/251311 But it would be nice if you provided `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. PS: do you really have no indexes in the table?

Comment: @zerkms Thank you for the linked question. Could you help me in a construction of the query with joining to CTE? I'm not sure where I should put my conditions. I updated my post with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFER)`.

Comment: Well, you need to at least add an index for the `sensor_id` column (since it's a FK anyway), then show the updated plan for it.

Comment: I would try an index on `(sensor_id, measurement_time)`

Comment: I added index on `(sensor_id, measurement_time)` and it executes now in about 300 ms! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Defozo: That is what I call a *supporting index* : the target for an FK *must* have at least a unique constraint, the referrer doesn't need it: you'll have to create that yourself. **Always**. (imagine the case of a cascading delete ...)

Answer (score 0):

Create a non-clustered index on the timestamp as you are filtering values depending upon timestamp. That will definitely help

Comment: All indexes are "non clustered" in Postgres