# Postgresql- Trying to get a list of results where a date range is null

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on converting results from a MySQL database to a Postgresql one, and finding random syntax issues that searching isn't helping with.

For this one: I am trying to return a list of results for users who have not created a job in our system for over 90 days. I've tried a few variations, but here is where my code is at right now:

```
 select  law_firms.name as "Law Firm"
from law_firms
left join jobs on jobs.law_firm_id = law_firms.id
  where jobs.id IN (SELECT jobs.created_at::date >= 90) IS NULL
  and law_firms.deleted_at IS NULL
  and law_firms.name not like '%Temp%"'
  and law_firms.name not like '%Individual%'
  GROUP BY law_firms.name
```

I've tried a few different variations of ::date between and CASTS, but it's coming back with an error message of **"ERROR: operator does not exist: date >= integer Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts"**

For reference, the MySQL code that worked in our BI originally was:

```
where `jobs`.`id` IN (SELECT `jobs`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND NOW()) IS NULL
```

Comment: Does the mySQL query not work as is? postgresql supports `NOW()` and `INTERVAL`. You need to change the `90 DAY` part, but that's it?

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Comment: `jobs.id IN (SELECT jobs.created_at::date >= 90) IS NULL` does not make any sense to me. Even if `jobs.created_at::date >= 90` did work, it would return a list of `boolean` values. So the condition would become `WHERE jobs.id in (true, false, true, false, ...) IS NULL` - does MySQL really support something like that?

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, isn't this as simple as converting the bracketed subquery

from:

```
SELECT `jobs`.`created_at` BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 90 DAY AND NOW()
```

To this:

```
SELECT jobs.created_at BETWEEN NOW() - interval '90 days' AND NOW()
```

edit: of course, you need to add `WHERE` and `FROM` to match the original subquery, but your example original subquery doesn't include it.

I think it would look like this:

```
SELECT jobs.created_at 
FROM jobs 
WHERE jobs.created_at BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL '90 DAY' AND NOW()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solving Strategy

- Get the most recent jobs for every law firm
- Filter out most recent jobs, that are younger than 90 days
- Join with table law_firm

#### Most Recent Job per Law Firm

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (law_firm_id) law_firm_id, created_at
FROM job
ORDER BY law_firm_id, created_at DESC
```

- `SELECT DISTINCT ON (law_firm_id)`

  - Will return every law_firm_id once
  - It will select the first row for a law_firm_id in the order of `ORDER BY`
  - `ORDER BY [...] created_at DESC` will return the youngest job for the law_firm_id

Postgres Docu: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT

#### Filter out Law Firms with Jobs younger than 90 days

Calculate the cutoff date in postgres with `INTERVAL`: `NOW() - INTERVAL '90 days'`

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (law_firm_id) law_firm_id, created_at
   FROM job
   ORDER BY law_firm_id, created_at DESC
) as j
WHERE j.created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL '90 days'
```

- `NOW() - INTERVAL '90 days'` - calculate cutoff timestamp
- `created_at` assuming it's a `timestamp` or `timestamp with time zone`

Postgres Docu: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

#### Final Query

```sql
SELECT law_firms.name as "Law Firm"
FROM law_firms
JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (law_firm_id) law_firm_id, created_at
   FROM job
   ORDER BY law_firm_id, created_at DESC
) as j
ON j.law_firm_id = law_firms.id
WHERE j.created_at < NOW() - INTERVAL '90 days'
  AND law_firms.deleted_at IS NULL
  AND law_firms.name not like '%Temp%"'
  AND law_firms.name not like '%Individual%'
```

- Query does not use `IN`, unfortunately the `IN` is not very fast in postgres (e.g. see: [postgres query with IN is very slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246746/postgres-query-with-in-is-very-slow))
- I assumed you wanted all firm that had a job at least once. If you needed all law firms with zero jobs, the query would be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below query:

```
select "Law Firm" from (
select  law_firms.id, law_firms.name "Law Firm", count(jobs.id) "rec_count"
from law_firms
left join jobs on jobs.law_firm_id = law_firms.id
  where jobs.created_at::date between  (current_date- interval '90 days') and current_date
  and law_firms.deleted_at IS NULL
  and law_firms.name not like '%Temp%"'
  and law_firms.name not like '%Individual%'
  GROUP BY 1,2
    ) tab
    where rec_count=0
```

In above query the sub query will get the count of all JOB IDs law firm wise in last 90 days. then we can filter the records with zero record count the get the desired result.

Apart from this: always use small letters for your column, table etc. naming. otherwise you have to surround it with `"` always.